# From where was the current class called in FLEX?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, apache-flex, flex3

I have a LoginView.mxml class that is being called from a number of places. I wanted to know if there exists a method to know from which class LoginView.mxml was called?

**EDIT**

I have not phrased the question well. Here is what the scenario is

I have a view called **LoginView.mxml** and 2 more views e.g. **AAAView.mxml** and **BBBView.mxml**. Both AAAView and BBBView call LoginView by using **navigator.pushView(LoginView)**.

Now I want some code in LoginView which can tell me whether AAAView has called it or not.

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=app_container_3.html

Comment: This link can be useful for you.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please help now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to navigator.pushView(viewToPopUp, data) is an object type. You can put anything you want in there. In your case, you might want to put a string that indicates the name of the View that this call is coded in.

Somewhere in AAAView:

```
protected function someButton_click(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     navigator.push(LoginView, "AAAView");
}
```

Then in your LoginView.mxml:

```
protected function loginView_creationComplete(e:Event):void
{
     if (data.toString() == "AAAView")
     {
       // do what you need if AAAView was the one that popped up LoginView
     }
     else ...
}
```

Each view has a data member of type object. It's null if your view wasn't navigator.pushViewed from another view, or if navigator.pushView didn't specify a second parameter.

You can have the if (data.toString() == "AAAView") block. in any function in the LoginView.